# How to register service dependency for ITokenAcquisition. (Microsoft.Identity.Web)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, azure-ad-msal

How to inject dependency for ITokenAcquisition. (Microsoft.Identity.Web)

I tried using below code in startup.cs file, it worked for me.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

**But how can we register ITokenAcquisition service dependency using AddSingleton<>()**

Comment: Maybe [this code](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) will help you.

Comment: The `ITokenAcquistionService` dependency should already be registered into your application with the call to the `EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi`.

Are you not able to inject `ITokenAcquisition` directly into your services?

Comment: I am not using EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi, I have used, services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
              .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd")).AddJwtBearer().

That's why I want to avoid using EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi() and inject ITokenAcquisition in another way.